# Saved Image file resolution does not equal to the Image from AcquireLatestImage

Tags: android, image, resolution

I used android camera2 API to capture image. All is fine and when I capture the image and try to save into a JPG file, the Image object retrieved from my ImageReader.acquireLatestImage has width=3264 and height=1836 (which is my desired size). However after I saved to the JPG file and I checked the resolution of the file, it becomes 1280x720 (which is the size of my preview surface). Not sure how can I have the image file resolution the same as my Image size?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Image oImage = null;
    File oImageFile = null;
    ByteBuffer oBuffer = null;
    byte[] oBytes = null;

    try {
        oImage = m_oImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
        oImageFile = CreateJPEG();

        Log.i("Log", String.format("Image Size Width: %d, Height: %d", oImage.getWidth(), oImage.getHeight()));
        // Image Size Width: 3264, Height: 1836

        oBuffer = oImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        oBytes = new byte[oBuffer.capacity()];
        oBuffer.get(oBytes);
        SaveBytesToFile(oBytes, oImageFile);
        oImage.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s(%s)", ex.toString(), "ImageGenerator.run"));
    }
}

private File CreateJPEG() {
    long nTime = 0;
    int nRandom = 0;
    File oDir = null;
    String sFilename = "";

    nTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    nRandom = new Random().nextInt(1000);
    oDir = new File(String.format("%s/%s", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyPhotos"));
    if (!oDir.exists()) {
        oDir.mkdir();
    }
    sFilename = String.format("%d%d.jpg", nTime, nRandom);

    return new File(oDir, sFilename);
}

private void SaveBytesToFile(byte[] oBytes, File oImageFile) {
    OutputStream oOutputStream = null;

    try {
        oOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(oImageFile);
        oOutputStream.write(oBytes);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s(%s)", ex.toString(), "ImageGenerator.SaveBytesToFile"));
    } finally {
        try {
            if (oOutputStream != null) {
                oOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("%s(%s)", ex.toString(), "ImageGenerator.SaveBytesToFile"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you check the resolution of the jpg file? getPlanes() returns one plane only?

Comment: I used a 3rd party File Explorer app to check the file properties, and it said the resolution of the file is 1280x720. Yes, getPlanes() returns one plane only.